# Architecture to share logic across MPA and SPA applications

Tags: c#, design, architecture, n-tier, asp.net-core

What in your opinion is good practice to handle the case where I want to have re-usable and shared logic that collects and returns my data from the database?

For example I have Multi Page Application and one day I decide to make Single Page Application out of it. I don't want to re-write much.

This brings up the question: How should I approach this problem?

### Case 1

- Both types of application talk directly to the exposed WebAPI which in turn talks to some class (like repository) making calls to the database. And then in case of SPA returning the JSON.
- There is a DLL with the logic and only WebAPI project uses this DLL, which probably means there are internal HTTP calls to the API in case of Multi Page Applications and it's the server making these requests.
- **Database access is not direct, goes through the service exposing the API, can be hosted on the same server.**

Wouldn't it be more expensive approach than the one as shown on the second image below? (because of the HTTP calls instead talking directly to the database)

[image: Architecture one]

### Case 2

- Multi Page Application doesn't know anything about WebAPI exposed to other clients (desktop, mobile, single page web apps). The repository (logic) class is instead shared with the WebAPI controllers and classic controllers that return View instead of data.
- There is a DLL with the logic and both projects depend on this DLL. Means no internal HTTP requests in case of MPA - less expensive?
- **Direct database access**

[image: Architecture two]

Which approach should I choose and why? Is the first approach more expensive than the other because of internal HTTP requests?

Comment: It appears that your multiple-page app in the second diagram *will only run on the server,* and not on any other workstations.  Is that correct?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes it is.

Comment: But is it serving web pages to any other workstations?

Comment: It is returning content, html so it is serving web pages to whoever visits the site

Comment: Traditionally, you talk directly to the database with server side applications.  I don't see any benefit to extending the JSON interface to that server... You would simply be adding another layer of indirection without good cause.

Comment: So I should go and create a class library with my logic or "Services" and then use it wherever I want, API controllers or MVC controllers I guess?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: I think it's not even possible to achieve what's on the first diagram, because if I did what's on the first diagram then I would have to somehow call controller from controller.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see you use C#. Do you think I can avoid "Repository" layer and communicate with the database directly from my "Service" layer? I was reading about onion architecture [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36655.onion-architecture-in-asp-net-core-mvc.aspx)

Comment: That would depend on whether or not you need the benefits that a [repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) provides.  If you're using EF, you might already be using the repository pattern and not even know it.

Comment: Yes I use repository pattern, and I wrap DbContext there. IMO I still can avoid additional service layer (wrapper for repository) and do all of this with "Repository" concept only. See this paste for comparsion: https://pastebin.com/0JdCWh4A

Comment: I don't know if services have any benefit over repositories if I do it right. I think separation of concerns and using multiple repositories inside services are the only benefit.

Comment: Don't forget, there are also costs.  If you're creating a repository layer merely for the sake of conforming to the architecture flavor of the week, you've just created a whole bunch of additional classes that all have to be written, maintained and read by others.

Comment: What would you suggest then to keep it simple and clean? Using DbContext directly without repository layer? So just pass DbContext to my Service layer directly and use it.

Comment: Your diagrams say that the database data goes through a layer called "My Logic," which I interpret as meaning that you won't be using the EF DataContext directly, beyond that layer.

Comment: That's true. I'm still concerned though whether or not separate services from repositories, or just use one of them and put my business logic into either service or repository. I still need to wrap CRUD operations when using services, but I think I will handle it somehow. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: "My Logic" consists currently of 1 layer which is repository, I was thinking to add another layer "service" on top of repository where I would put my business logic and repository would only serve as data provider with simple CRUD operations(wrapping DbContext)

Comment: What you call "logic" it's main app business. Isn't it? In some practices, you would name these "domain" and domain may involve entities, value objects, repositories, services and other components strictly involved with the business and its solution. WEB APIs or Web Services are mere drivers that grant access to the domain. So why would you split code by repositories vs services if both are "logic" or part of the "business". Additionally, each subsequent layer might have its own services or components. Each of them consuming domain's services and repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I would treat both applications, SPA (client side) and Multi-page (server side)  as stand-alone client applications and would thus go for Case 1 solution.

From your comments I see that the Multi-page application is running on the server side and is serving content to someone, so that would make it a client application. Currently it resides on this server but perhaps in the future it might be moved to another location where database calls would not be possible from, a "middleware" WebAPI would come in handy then.

Comment: Exactly. Also, http requests are pretty cheap, and thus it's always better to favor  separation of concerns over saving some bytes.